# Calculate Volume in TimeScaleDB for OHLC

Tags: timescaledb

I am  new to Timescale DB (just migrated from MongoDB) to store raw trades and then generate OHLCV using their official docs here :

```
https://docs.timescale.com/getting-started/latest/add-data/
```

I was successful in moving my data from Mongo to Timescale, create hyper table, materialzed view, and continuous aggregation.

However, the example showed only OHLC (not OHLCV), and so my charts is showing bars perfectly, but with no volume at the bottom (using TradingView charting library). Below are some queries that got me this far.

**Problem :**

```
Need some assistance figuring out how to calculate volume and add to materialized view ?
```

**Created Table :**

```
CREATE TABLE trades (
  timestamp TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  market TEXT NOT NULL,
  price DOUBLE PRECISION NULL,
  volume INT NULL
);
```

**Created Index** :

```
CREATE INDEX ix_symbol_time ON trades (market, timestamp DESC);
```

**Create Time-bucket :**

```
SELECT
  time_bucket('1 min', "timestamp") AS day,
  market,
  max(price) AS high,
  first(price, timestamp) AS open,
  last(price, timestamp) AS close,
  min(price) AS low
FROM trades srt
GROUP BY day, market
ORDER BY day DESC, market;
```

**Create Materialized view :**

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW candlestick_one_minute
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT
  time_bucket('1 min', "timestamp") AS day,
  market,
  max(price) AS high,
  first(price, timestamp) AS open,
  last(price, timestamp) AS close,
  min(price) AS low
FROM trades srt
GROUP BY day, market
ORDER BY day DESC, market;
```

**Add Continuous Aggregation :**

```
SELECT add_continuous_aggregate_policy('candlestick_one_minute',
  start_offset => INTERVAL '3 days',
  end_offset => INTERVAL '1 hour',
  schedule_interval => INTERVAL '1 days');
```

Comment: Hi! The correct way to calculate the volume column depends on the raw data you ingest. Eg.: sometimes you need to do a `SUM(volume)`, other times you might need a `LAST(volume, time)`. So what does the `volume` field store in your trades table?

Comment: @AttilaToth It stores the volume of that particular trade. For e.g. 

if 1 BTC buy order was executed against a sell order of 1 BTC. The raw trades.volume =1

Comment: @AttilaToth The solution I am looking for is how to modify the existing VIEW, continuous Aggregation, and time_bucket to support Volume. Being new to all this, I really don't want to spoil what is already done, by experimenting new things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new continuous aggregate that includes a volume column as well:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW candlestick_one_minute_new
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT
  time_bucket('1 min', "timestamp") AS day,
  market,
  max(price) AS high,
  first(price, timestamp) AS open,
  last(price, timestamp) AS close,
  min(price) AS low,
  SUM(volume) AS volume
FROM trades srt
GROUP BY day, market;
```

See if it does what you expect it to do.

Add a refresh policy (this is the same one you have currently):

```sql
SELECT add_continuous_aggregate_policy('candlestick_one_minute_new',
  start_offset => INTERVAL '3 days',
  end_offset => INTERVAL '1 hour',
  schedule_interval => INTERVAL '1 days');
```

Then, if everything looks fine with the new view, you can drop the previous view:

```sql
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW candlestick_one_minute;
```

And rename the new one:

```sql
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW candlestick_one_minute_new RENAME TO candlestick_one_minute
```

Comment: Great. Let me give it a try, test, and get back  with an update ! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Works perfectly. I have some follow-up questions in regards to managing multiple resolutions with TimeScale, should I post it here as comment or you want me to create a new question ? Btw, thanks for all the help so far, I really appreciate it. Have successfully wasted more than a month trying to figure out OHLCV thing, tried MySQL, Mongo, and in the end Timescale solved it exactly the way I wanted !

Comment: You can ask here in the comments. Or better, post to our Community Forum: timescale.com/forum

Comment: I have create the post in forum, awaiting approval. Have also posted same here too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74190782/what-are-best-practices-to-manage-different-resolution-with-timescale-db