# What are best practices to manage different Resolution with Timescale DB

Tags: timescaledb

I am pretty new to TSDB and especially with TimeScale DB. I have successfully managed to store the 1Min OHLCV in Materialized with, setup continous aggregation and everything is running fine.

I am using TradingView Charting library on the FE which automatically creates 5min, 15min, 30min and other charts from the 1min OHLCV data.

My response object for TradingView /history request :

```
{
"s":"ok",
"t":[1666703100,1666703160,1666703220],
"o":[19288.1,19285.4,19289.1],
"h":[19294.8,19289.1,19289.1],
"l":[19285.4,19285.4,19288.7],
"c":[19285.4,19289.0,19288.8],
"v":[180.10899999999992,83.95100000000004]
}
```

the Result I get from TimeScale DB :

```
{
"day": 2022-10-22 13:35:00+05:30,
"open": 19230.326,
"high":19500,
"low":19200.20,
"close":19250.68,
"volume":2.658
}
```

So I have to loop through ResultSet from DB -> map to my response object -> send to TV.

Now as the data grows, 1min candles take up lot of processing due to this loop.

1. What should be an ideal way from performance and resource optimization point of view
   to manage multiple resoution with TimeScale DB ?
2. Any better way to map the DB result to my required response without looping ? Bit allergic to loop with large data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timescaledb is testing an experimental set of functions to cover ohlc and soon ohlcv will also be available.

You can [rollup](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/financial-analysis/rollup/) it over ohlc data but not use materialized views over materialized views (at least for now).

Let me share a small example that maybe can help.

First, a simple ticks table to store the trade events:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ticks
( time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    symbol varchar,
    price double precision,
    volume int);

SELECT create_hypertable('ticks', 'time', chunk_time_interval => INTERVAL '1 day');
```

Now, let's create the base ohlcv from 1 minute being the most granular pre-calculated materialized view:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW _ohlcv_1m
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
    SELECT time_bucket('1 minute'::interval, time),
      symbol,
      toolkit_experimental.ohlc(time, price),
      sum(volume) as volume
    FROM ticks
    GROUP BY 1,2 WITH DATA;
```

As the continuous aggregates in the top of another continuous aggregates is not allowed, we can create a simple view and benefit from rollup that will "merge" the previous ohlc structures.

```sql
CREATE VIEW _ohlcv_1h AS
    SELECT time_bucket('1 hour'::interval, time_bucket),
      symbol,
      toolkit_experimental.rollup(ohlc) as ohlc,
      sum(volume) as volume
    FROM _ohlcv_1m
    GROUP BY 1,2;
```

The views don't have access to the values directly, so, we can create views to access the ohlcv values and the time of each event.

```sql
CREATE VIEW ohlcv_1m as
SELECT time_bucket,
  symbol,
  toolkit_experimental.open(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.open_time(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.high(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.high_time(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.low(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.low_time(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.close(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.close_time(ohlc),
  volume
FROM _ohlcv_1m;

CREATE VIEW ohlcv_1h as
SELECT time_bucket,
  symbol,
  toolkit_experimental.open(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.open_time(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.high(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.high_time(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.low(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.low_time(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.close(ohlc),
  toolkit_experimental.close_time(ohlc),
  volume
FROM _ohlcv_1h;
```

Now, seeding some data for tests:

```sql
INSERT INTO ticks
SELECT time, 'SYMBOL', (random()*30)::int, 100*(random()*10)::int
FROM generate_series(TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
                 TIMESTAMP '2000-01-02 00:00:00' + INTERVAL '1 hour',
             INTERVAL '1 second') AS time;
```

Testing the final views:

```sql
playground=# select time_bucket, open, high, low, close, volume from ohlcv_1h ORDER BY time_bucket LIMIT 1;
┌────────────────────────┬──────┬──────┬─────┬───────┬─────────┐
│      time_bucket       │ open │ high │ low │ close │ volume  │
├────────────────────────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼───────┼─────────┤
│ 2000-01-01 00:00:00-02 │   13 │   30 │   0 │     8 │ 1809600 │
└────────────────────────┴──────┴──────┴─────┴───────┴─────────┘
(1 row)

playground=# select time_bucket, open, high, low, close, volume from ohlcv_1m ORDER BY time_bucket LIMIT 60
;
┌────────────────────────┬──────┬──────┬─────┬───────┬────────┐
│      time_bucket       │ open │ high │ low │ close │ volume │
├────────────────────────┼──────┼──────┼─────┼───────┼────────┤
│ 2000-01-01 00:00:00-02 │   13 │   30 │   0 │    25 │  32700 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:01:00-02 │    0 │   30 │   0 │     2 │  33000 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:02:00-02 │    1 │   30 │   0 │     6 │  26300 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:03:00-02 │    4 │   30 │   1 │    28 │  30300 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:04:00-02 │   30 │   30 │   0 │    27 │  29200 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:05:00-02 │   24 │   29 │   2 │    16 │  27500 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:06:00-02 │    9 │   28 │   0 │    15 │  30200 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:07:00-02 │   21 │   30 │   2 │     3 │  30300 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:08:00-02 │   10 │   29 │   1 │     3 │  35300 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:09:00-02 │    6 │   30 │   0 │    16 │  26700 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:10:00-02 │   10 │   30 │   0 │    24 │  30300 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:11:00-02 │   30 │   30 │   1 │    27 │  29800 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:12:00-02 │    6 │   30 │   1 │    26 │  25500 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:13:00-02 │   13 │   29 │   0 │    22 │  30400 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:14:00-02 │    2 │   30 │   1 │    21 │  30800 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:15:00-02 │   22 │   30 │   0 │    15 │  31400 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:16:00-02 │   10 │   30 │   1 │     8 │  33700 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:17:00-02 │    3 │   30 │   1 │    22 │  27600 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:18:00-02 │   13 │   29 │   0 │     5 │  31400 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:19:00-02 │   17 │   29 │   1 │    16 │  30900 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:20:00-02 │   24 │   29 │   1 │    10 │  26500 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:21:00-02 │   16 │   29 │   1 │     9 │  34100 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:22:00-02 │   14 │   30 │   0 │    22 │  31500 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:23:00-02 │   10 │   30 │   1 │     1 │  28700 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:24:00-02 │    1 │   30 │   1 │     1 │  32900 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:25:00-02 │   11 │   30 │   1 │    24 │  25700 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:26:00-02 │   21 │   28 │   0 │     1 │  32100 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:27:00-02 │    1 │   30 │   0 │    23 │  33800 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:28:00-02 │    1 │   30 │   1 │    22 │  30100 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:29:00-02 │   15 │   30 │   0 │     6 │  26900 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:30:00-02 │   15 │   29 │   1 │     7 │  32800 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:31:00-02 │    9 │   30 │   0 │     7 │  30200 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:32:00-02 │   16 │   30 │   0 │    10 │  28000 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:33:00-02 │    6 │   30 │   1 │     9 │  28800 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:34:00-02 │    6 │   30 │   1 │     9 │  30300 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:35:00-02 │   20 │   29 │   0 │    17 │  30800 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:36:00-02 │   27 │   29 │   0 │    21 │  28400 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:37:00-02 │   29 │   30 │   0 │    20 │  30100 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:38:00-02 │   23 │   30 │   0 │     5 │  30300 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:39:00-02 │    1 │   30 │   0 │    24 │  34000 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:40:00-02 │   10 │   30 │   0 │    30 │  27500 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:41:00-02 │    3 │   30 │   0 │    20 │  32200 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:42:00-02 │    2 │   29 │   0 │    12 │  29400 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:43:00-02 │    5 │   29 │   0 │     4 │  31800 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:44:00-02 │   22 │   30 │   0 │     6 │  32700 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:45:00-02 │   11 │   29 │   1 │     9 │  30400 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:46:00-02 │   10 │   30 │   0 │     1 │  26700 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:47:00-02 │   12 │   30 │   0 │    17 │  28400 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:48:00-02 │   15 │   30 │   0 │    16 │  30800 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:49:00-02 │    6 │   30 │   0 │    29 │  27900 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:50:00-02 │   20 │   30 │   0 │    28 │  26500 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:51:00-02 │    7 │   30 │   0 │    14 │  30500 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:52:00-02 │   23 │   29 │   0 │     4 │  31200 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:53:00-02 │   26 │   30 │   1 │    10 │  31000 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:54:00-02 │   24 │   30 │   1 │     3 │  30200 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:55:00-02 │    3 │   30 │   0 │    20 │  32800 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:56:00-02 │   24 │   30 │   1 │    12 │  27300 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:57:00-02 │   19 │   30 │   0 │    26 │  30600 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:58:00-02 │    8 │   29 │   1 │    21 │  33500 │
│ 2000-01-01 00:59:00-02 │   10 │   30 │   1 │     8 │  28900 │
└────────────────────────┴──────┴──────┴─────┴───────┴────────┘
(60 rows)
```

For the part 2 of your question, you can use `array_agg` from postgresql to be concatenating the data. Example:

```sql
select array_agg(time_bucket) as t,
array_agg(open) as o,
array_agg(high) as h,
array_agg(low) as l,
array_agg(close) as c,
array_agg(volume) as v from ohlcv_1m group BY time_bucket('5 m', time_bucket) limit 3 ;
```

I'm limiting to 3 records just for the sake of readability, here are the results:

````sql
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────────────┬─────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                               t                                                                │        o        │        h         │      l      │       c        │                v                │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────────────┼─────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ {"2000-01-01 00:02:00-02","2000-01-01 00:00:00-02","2000-01-01 00:01:00-02","2000-01-01 00:03:00-02","2000-01-01 00:04:00-02"} │ {16,0,27,29,14} │ {30,30,30,29,30} │ {1,0,2,1,0} │ {27,14,23,1,0} │ {29500,32400,32100,28500,25400} │
│ {"2000-01-01 00:07:00-02","2000-01-01 00:08:00-02","2000-01-01 00:05:00-02","2000-01-01 00:09:00-02","2000-01-01 00:06:00-02"} │ {22,26,9,17,5}  │ {30,30,29,30,29} │ {0,2,0,1,0} │ {21,5,18,14,5} │ {29000,28700,31600,30700,31200} │
│ {"2000-01-01 00:12:00-02","2000-01-01 00:11:00-02","2000-01-01 00:13:00-02","2000-01-01 00:10:00-02","2000-01-01 00:14:00-02"} │ {29,20,27,19,2} │ {30,30,29,30,30} │ {0,0,0,1,0} │ {1,17,21,9,16} │ {28400,31500,30800,25900,32100} │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴──────────────────┴─────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘```
````

Comment: Very nice feature. Does `toolkit_experimental.ohlc` offer some benefits of creating `open`, `high`, `low,`, `close` aggregate columns by hand, or is it just a shortcut?

Comment: It works like a shortcut.  An interesting fact is that you can also use window functions and rollup  the window which is quite fast and convenient :)